# Asking something "just for general knowledge" - acceptable idiom?

Tags: phrase-request, idioms

can I use this words (**just for general knowledge**) in the following context?

Miss. Liz is a secretary of my department at the university.

Context:

> "Miss Liz, **just for general knowledge**, can I combine my law study (L.L.B) with
>   another studies in another faculties? (like biology or something else
>   in the science)"

I mean that I don't want really yet to do that, but I ask it just to know and as an option for the future. I hope that I explained myself understandably.

Answer (score 11):

This is not idiomatic. The bare noun *knowledge* suggests a general body of knowledge rather than a known fact, unless that is explicitly specified with an *of* PP or *that* clause.

I think most people would say *Just so I know*, or *Just for the sake of knowing*, or *Just out of curiosity*, or perhaps *Just in case I ever need to know*.

Answer (score 4):

"Hypothetically speaking" is quite common.  Also "with another studies" "in another faculties" should be "with other studies" "in another faculty".

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean in "Hypothetically speaking"?

Comment: @Dory - in the world of science, not all hypotheses are accepted and confirmed, but it's safe to advance hypotheses, sometimes just in order to probe possibilities. So it's as if you're proposing a hypothesis: "What if I decide to combine courses? Would it be allowed?". You do not say outright "I've decided to combine courses".

Answer (score 4):

In British English, an idiomatic phrase would be "Just for interest, ..." or "Just out of interest, ..."

See meanings 1 and 3 of "interest" in http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/interest

Comment: or even "out of interest", especially when at the start of a sentence.

Comment: *Just **as a matter** of interest* you might like to note that Google Books claims [about 4,470 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22just+as+a+matter+of+interest%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) for that search string. OP's example clearly implies the *speaker's* "interest", but in my version it's something (potentially) of interest to whoever is being *addressed*.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, "for curiosity's sake", or "out of curiosity".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is common at all, but I've heard the phrase "Just for knowledge's sake" used to convey that meaning.